# iOS Simulator in iOS 7 SDK

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, xcode5

Been looking at iOS 7 SDK tonight, one thing I noticed, have they dropped the iPhone "Skin" for the simulator in iOS 7? I only seem to be able to select, iPhone 3.5/4 inch Retina or iPad/iPad Retina, they all just have a black border, I prefer to test with the skinned simulator non retina as it's alot faster, any ideas how to get it back?

Comment: Shell out the big bucks for a retina MacBook Pro. :) They have the border since it can fit on the screen.  You can't use a non-retina iPhone because no non-retina iPhone supports iOS7.

Comment: iOS 7 doesn't support non-retina iPhones, so that is why you cannot select one in the devices menu

Comment: Thanks guys! - So If i'm getting this correctly it'll only skin on a retina mbp and not on my 2010 mbp? Must upgrade soon!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

iOS7 is only available on iPhone 4+ which means only retina displays, so it wouldn't make sense to be able to test iOS7 on a non retina simulator.

I notice that if I run the simulator on my Retina MBP I get the skinned simulator, but if I run it on my regular 24" LCD monitor it appears without the skin and the simulator is much larger.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, will mark as correct after the 10 minutes, so Apple are restricting the skin on non retina Macs?!

Comment: @JohnWoods yep.  retina mac or no skin.

Comment: Yes, because the simulator on non retina displays is obviously like double the size and the skin doesn't fit.

Comment: Time to upgrade I think, maybe wait for the Retina air :)

Comment: Wait for the Haswell MBP. Supposed to offer much better battery life. I think they are coming out in the next few months.

Comment: @Nick: Open the simulator and look in the `Window` menu. There should be a Scale or Zoom option. You can reduce the size of the simulator there.

Comment: @StephenMelvin Oh that's neat. Thanks.